# How can i lazyload a table while the user have the ability to search data in it?

Tags: javascript, api, dom, lazy-loading

So i have a huge amount of data to load in a **table** , maybe thousands of rows and i am fetching the data from an **API**.

Now i have the obvious problem that the DOM will take so much time to render.

I googled about **lazy-loading** and i'am thinking it may be a solution but i'am not sure because the user can *search the data* (front-end search), so i'am afraid that would not be possible if the data is not even rendered in the DOM.

I am asking for a javascript solution even if i have to use a library or so.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You've got a couple of options here:

- Do the search on the back-end if possible
- Load the data into a Javascript array only, then just render a small section of it at a time, and search the array.

It seems unlikely you'll need a library, searching the contents of an array of data should be straightforward.

**Edit**

Okay, if putting search functionality on the back-end is impossible it's still fairly easy to store and search thousands of rows of a table in-browser. The below working example generates 10000 rows of random data and shows up to 15 of them that match the user's search. Adding pagination should not be challenging. In the final loop, page one is values of j < 15. So for page 2 print rows where 15 ≤ j < 30, for page 3 print when 30 ≤ j < 45, etc.

The important thing for memory consumption is to not store all your data in the DOM and just hide the rows the user shouldn't see. In this example there are only ever 15 `<tr>` elements in the DOM, all the data is stored in an array and only the user's current view is rendered.

```js
const data = [];
const table = document.querySelector('table');
const input = document.querySelector('input');

function printRow(row) {
  // in reality you have to escape data for HTML, this is just a quick demo
  table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<tr><td>${row.id}</td><td>${row.r}</td><td>${row.s}</td>`);
}

// Generate dummy data
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  data.push({'id': i,
    'r': Math.random().toString(36),
    's': Math.random().toString(36)});
}

// Display first page of data
for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  printRow(data[i]);
}

input.addEventListener('input', e => {
  table.innerHTML = '';
  for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < data.length & j < 15; i++) {
    if (data[i].r.indexOf(input.value) >= 0 || data[i].s.indexOf(input.value) >= 0) {
      printRow(data[i]);
      j++;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input>
<table border="1"></table>
```

Comment: I am just dealing with the front-end stuff in this project, and the data i am fetching is the users. The response from the server is an array of all users, already that takes time. In the second option, do you mean that i should store the response in an array than looping through it and wait a little with every step?

Comment: Yes, store all the data in an array and loop over it. There shouldn't be a need to wait for anything if there are only thousands of users as you say. I've put a working example in the answer with random data, and searching 10000 rows feels instant on my machine.